# What might cause WooCommerce filters to stop working in the newest Wordpress version?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woothemes

I am setting up Wordpress theme but the shop filters stoped working. (Low to High, Hight to Low, Price filter, Newest) I didn't have that issue before.

I need advise what might have caused the issue.

- Wordpress version 5.2.2
- Woo version 3.6.4
- Chromium theme 1.1.5

I have updated all of the plugins and re-install Wordpress to 5.2.2 again.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

I have updated all of the plugins and Wordpress to the latest version. I updated the database as well. I haven't written any code in functions.php which can mess the filters.

I don't have a code because it is a generic problem.

Comment: The theme also need to be updated. ¿Is your theme up to date?

Comment: I will give it a try and see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the newest Woocommerce version there were changes in the database related to the filters as well.

**Solution:**
I updated the Woocommerce database to the latest version.